# Vertically mirroring the screen in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, camera, coordinates, screen, viewport

I'm developing a game in which the screen layout is different for right and lefty players, so i'll put a button in it to mirror the screen vertically.

For displaying textures and fonts, i use a single scene2D stage with actors and labels. The stage's viewport type is FitViewport.

How can i swap between the right and left layouts?
Is there something already done to do it on the viewport-side?

Is it only a matter of switching coordinates from bottom-left to bottom-right?
I can do that on the viewport camera, but what about all the textures? How can i change an actor's coordinate system?

Thank you all

Comment: As one example, you could render your scene to an off-screen target then draw that target onto the backbuffer. While drawing, you can simply reverse the X-component of the UV's to mirror it. Also, if you are currently viewing the scene from the "front side" (Z+), move the camera to the "back side" (Z-), instead; geometry *appears* reversed (probably need to reverse culling).

Comment: Please consider the examples in my comment and add a few specific details regarding any of the mechanics I've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Render your part of scene to frame buffer object, than draw frame buffer textureRegion flipped where you want (buffer.getColorBufferTexture())

Comment: Please provide some more info (an example would be nice)